# VB Excel Looping Dynamic Query

Tags: excel, vb.net, ms-access, vba

I would like to ask about Vb Excel,

here's the code

```
Sub connectDatabase()
Dim conn As New Connection
Dim rs As New Recordset
Dim rangeA As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim kodeKabupaten As String, deskripsiKecamatan As String, deskripsiKelurahan As String
rangeA = Application.ActiveSheet.UsedRange

    strcon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
    "Data Source=D:\Kepemerintahan.accdb;"
    conn.Open (strcon)



    For i = LBound(rangeA, 1) + 1 To UBound(rangeA, 1)
        qry = "SELECT * FROM Kepemerintahan where kode_kabupaten = '" & Cells(i, 5).Value & "' and deskripsi_kecamatan = '" & Cells(i, 7).Value & "' and deskripsi_kelurahan = '" & Cells(i, 9).Value & "'"
        rs.Open qry, conn, adOpenKeyset
        If IsNull(qry) Then
            markError (i)
        End If
    Next i
    rs.Close
    conn.Close
End Sub

Function markError(ByVal i As Integer)
    Cells(i, 5).Font.Color = vbRed
    Cells(i, 7).Font.Color = vbRed
    Cells(i, 9).Font.Color = vbRed
End Function
```

the problem is it's only allow me to do one iteration.
the error says "Operation is not allowed when the object is open"

i know it's because there's rs.open in the iteration which mean I keep opening an opened connection.

any suggest?

any help will be appreciated! 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put rs.close before `next i` as each iteration is a separate recordset.

You may also need to move the connection (conn.open and conn.close) inside the loop, I know I have in mine in the past but I am not sure if it was necessity or just what I did at the time.

Comment: Hi Dan, Do you know how to check whether the query return error or not?

Comment: Sure, I do this: `If RS.EOF Then` straight after the `RS.Open` line, if it is true then you know it has returned nothing. If you are looking for an actual return of an SQL error then it should parse the error and fire of the error object. Can you give me a specific example of what you would expect to see as the error if you ran the query in an SQL session?